# Pre Processing Terraform Locals

Tags: terraform

I have a bunch of TF locals,,,, which uses some ternary operator,, when i was pass var.env stg, it works fine,

```
locals {
  allowed_roles = [
    "rqm-airflow-task-prd",
    "${var.env == "stg" ? "rqm-airflow-task-stg" : "" }",
    "rqm-airflow-task-rnd",
    "rqm-ecs-pag_mock-task-role-prd",
    "${var.env == "stg" ? "rqm-ecs-pag_mock-task-role-stg" : "" }"
}
data "aws_iam_role" "allowed_roles" {
  count = "${length(local.allowed_roles)}"
  name  = "${local.allowed_roles[count.index]}"
}
```

but the stg  is a environment which is dynamic and does not persist always,
So the ternary operator values become empty "" when the stg env is deleted,  the code is re run with var.env as say “prd” and then `data.aws_iam_role`  fails.

```
Error: Error refreshing state: 1 error occurred:
    * data.aws_iam_role.allowed_roles: 4 errors occurred:
    * data.aws_iam_role.allowed_roles[7]: data.aws_iam_role.allowed_roles.7: error reading IAM Role (): InvalidParameter: 1 validation error(s) found.
- minimum field size of 1, GetRoleInput.RoleName.
    * data.aws_iam_role.allowed_roles[1]: data.aws_iam_role.allowed_roles.1: error reading IAM Role (): InvalidParameter: 1 validation error(s) found.
- minimum field size of 1, GetRoleInput.RoleName.
```

is there a way to pre process this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like what you need here is the result of [the `compact` function](https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/functions/compact.html):

> `compact` takes a list of strings and returns a new list with any empty string elements removed.

```
locals {
  allowed_roles = compact([
    "rqm-airflow-task-prd",
    var.env == "stg" ? "rqm-airflow-task-stg" : "",
    "rqm-airflow-task-rnd",
    "rqm-ecs-pag_mock-task-role-prd",
    var.env == "stg" ? "rqm-ecs-pag_mock-task-role-stg" : "",
  ])
}
```